# java.lang.NullPointerException in Spark running in dataproc

Tags: scala, apache-spark, google-cloud-dataproc

Hello everyone I've some strange problem,

When I run my jar to execute spark task with dataproc I got `java.lang.NullPointerException` when it comme to save it or to show results.
But when I run the same jar with spark_shell in dataproc there are no error.

Why?

Thank you for the help

Comment: Hi! We're going to need a bit more info here: Can you print the error stack trace? Can you also share your code with us?

Comment: Thank you @Koedlt,
I change `Some(value)`to `Option(value)` now it ok